# See the request that CURL is making with PHP CURL library

Tags: php, curl, resources, request

I'm trying to view the actual request made by the curl_exec($curl) function.  I am using the built in CURL functions in PHP.

When I do something like this -

```
curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
error_log(print_r($curl
```

I get a value of 1, which I assume is because it is a resource.  I am looking to view the actual request being made, something like the following I would use via Terminal

```
$ curl https://z3nburmaglot.zendesk.com -u japeterson@zendes.com:password z3nburmaglot.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/25757394850.json -X PUT -v -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"user": {"name": "James", "email": "japeterson@zendes.com"}}'
```

Is there anyway I can view the request the CURL resource is making like the above?  This will help with debugging so I know if it is properly formatting the request and what is missing.

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Comment: If you want what you'd put in terminal, echo it out: `echo "curl ".$url." -u ".$json['email'].":".$json['password'] etc...`

Comment: Hey hindmost and user1947561, thanks for the info but I actually asked how to make it a terminal command.  I understand that I can make my own by echoing it, but I was just wondering if there was a native function that would print it like a terminal command.  hindmost - RTFQ